# serilog shared file with retainedFileCountLimit

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have very big solution that use ILogger<T> with serilog for each class, all of them write logs to same file with shared : true.
the problem is retainedFileCountLimit doesn’t work for me because everyone count for himself, is there any option to make them all write to same file (shared: true) and also retain only 10 files?

this is my configuration:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/PrinterApi.log",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 2,
          "shared": true,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50000,
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [{Level:u3}] [{ThreadId}] [{SourceContext:1}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Destructure": [
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumDepth",
        "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 4 }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength",
        "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 100 }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount",
        "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 10 }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

tried to have only 10 combined files but serilog create more and more because its 10 per logger